# Style Input time CSS

Tags: css

I am trying to create a box like below picture.
This box will use for time and other two-digit numbers.

[image]

I putted my code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/L4L35/1/)
I have some problems and questions:

- Boxes in picture seems have two-color borders. outside is a color (color="#706f6f") and inside like shadow . with what technique I can create this inside border? Is this CSS3 effect ?
- I think my code style classification is not good.would you please help me to make it better?
- I don't know where should I put colons(:) between days hours mins and secs ?
- Last question is where is better to putt texts under boxes ? (DAYS , HOURS , MINS , SECS) Is it better to put them in separate Div container ?

Comment: It looks to me that the example picture uses an image as a background for the number boxes. Quotation marks == colons?

Comment: @Juhana you mean I should put background picture for Div ? and we can't create them with css ?
oh I edited my question (colons is right ! :] I'm new in english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this **[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/L4L35/2/)**.

1. You can add an inset shadow with CSS, but that is all. Like the already given answers and comments say, you might want to consider using a background image.
2. There is nothing wrong with your syntax, but it indeed could need a little refresh ;)
3. You *always* have to write your markup like there is no style sheet. So the colons are placed between the labels and the corresponding digits.
4. See 3.

The markup now shows like:

```
<div id="digits">
    <p>Days<span class="colon">: </span><span class="digits">10</span></p>
    <p>Hours<span class="colon">: </span><span class="digits">00</span></p>
    <p>Mins<span class="colon">: </span><span class="digits">00</span></p>
    <p>Secs<span class="colon last">: </span><span class="digits">00</span></p>
</div>
```

You could narrow it down to **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/L4L35/3/)**:

```
<div id="digits">
    <p>Days<span>: </span><span>10</span></p>
    <p>Hours<span>: </span><span>00</span></p>
    <p>Mins<span>: </span><span>00</span></p>
    <p>Secs<span class="last">: </span><span>00</span></p>
</div>
```

Tweak it a bit further as you like.

Comment: Thank you so much :] It was very helpful.
What's this selector ? #digits span + span

Comment: That is the adjacent selector. See [selectors](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Answer (score 1):

use this img as background for your divs:

[image]

then place black text on it in a condensed font. add a border to the divs, like in the images and give the wrapper a matching background color.

Answer (score 0):

I would create the numbers as an image sprite with the inner shadows that could be split left and right:

```
00
11
22
33
44
55
66
77
88
99
```

Then I would build a png overlay with transparent cutouts to mask the number images.